# ReactJS: When should setState be guarded by isMounted?

Tags: reactjs

The documentation for the reactjs `isMounted` API mentions that:

> You can use this method to guard asynchronous calls to `setState()` or
>   `forceUpdate()`.

My primary question is when *should* a call to `setState()` by guarded by a call to `isMounted()`?

In the [Initial AJAX Tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html the `setState` used in the XHR callback uses the `isMounted()` guard, but is this required?

A secondary question is, if it is required why is it so? It seems the check itself is very simple and could be inlined into the `setState()` without any significant performance penalty, but with a large simplification in API usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically, isMounted is needed if the component could be unmounted when the callback is called.

The best practice is to avoid this in componentWillUnmount e.g. aborting an ajax request, canceling a timeout, or unsubscribing from an event.

Arguably the api is simpler this way because setState doesn't silently fail if it's called at an inappropriate time.  Silently failing causes a lot of bugs that are difficult to track down.